# jQuery focus() page scroll length

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, cross-browser

I've got a code like this:

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="$('#newMsgTxt').focus();">New message</a>
<div style="min-height: 1300px;"></div>
<textarea id="newMsgTxt"></textarea>
<div style="min-height: 500px;"></div>
```

And here is the problem:
After I click the link, in different browsers the page scroll to a different position.

Example of `textarea` position on the screen after the click:

**Chrome:** *center*
**FF:** *bottom*
**Opera:** *top*

How can I make all browsers work like Chrome do?

Comment: Try to add return false; within your onclick

Comment: *Side-note*: always try to avoid inline JS, makes your code less readable (almost ugly), it's hard to debug and I need a coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var o = $('#newMsgTxt').focus().offset().top, $w = $(window);
    $w.scrollTop(o - ($w.height() / 2));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2BHRw/

Comment: is the e.preventDefault nessescary when there is no valid href?

Comment: True, but if you want the link to work without JS it could be useful to add it. (ofc in this case you got a point)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
onclick="$('#newMsgTxt').focus().val($('#newMsgTxt').val());
```

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the val from the same element ? Is it that the cursor will be at the end of the previous content ?

Comment: Yes. Could be that is the problem here!

Answer (score 0):

**Html :**

```
<a href="" id="newMessage">New message</a>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newMessage').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#newMsgTxt').focus();
    });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/jxZw2/

Answer (score 0):

This is because of different scroll position ,

You can test by using `console.log(window.scrollY)` onclicking the `link`
So you have to code for this to align it in center.

And the code is like

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e){
        $('#newMsgTxt').focus();
        var offsetTop = offset().top; 
        $(window).scrollTop(offsetTop - ($(window).height() / 2));
    });
});
```

And your html like:

```
<a href="javascript://">New message</a>
<div style="min-height: 1300px;"></div>
<textarea id="newMsgTxt">gfg</textarea>
<div style="min-height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try with below code......my naming is not good...so, replace with as per your idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>

       function test() {
           var o = $('#newMsgTxt').focus().offset().top, $w = $(window);
                $w.scrollTop(o - ($w.height() / 2));
       }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<a  onclick="test();">New message</a>
<div style="min-height: 1300px;vertical-align:top;"></div>
<textarea id="newMsgTxt" ></textarea>
<div style="min-height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```